# How do I create a button to go back from the settings page

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Image to my error

[image: 1]

I'm new to Android app development and I created a new settings activity from the provided templates. I'd like to create a button which redirects the user back to the main screen(I figured this part out), though I am unable to create a .

the image shows where I'm currently stuck

Comment: You don't really need to.  On Android, there's always the back button in the 3 button menu (or the back gesture if you use gesture controls).

Comment: @GabeSechan what if the user is using picture-in-picture mode? Then, none of that would work.

Answer (score 0):

In **PreferenceCategory** tag add

```
<Preference android:title="Exit" android:key="exit"/>
```

Then in class add this code:

```
Preference button = (Preference)getPreferenceManager().findPreference("exit");
    button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
            finish();   
            return true;
        }
    });
```